# Preserving the GLBlendFunc

Tags: opengl, glblendfunc

I need to preserve the current GlBlendFunc so  can restore it after I do some work.  It seems that this is not one of the attributes that can be saved with GLPushAttrib, is there some other similar method I can use to preserve the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glGet` with `GL_BLEND_SRC` and `GL_BLEND_DST` (and `glIsEnabled(GL_BLEND)`, if you're not sure whether it's enabled).